# PHP Multi Dimensional Array : Phone Prefix vs Courier Name

Tags: php

I'm thinking to use Array to store this tiny data instead using Database. But, I have difficulties to 'call' the data since this is Multi Dimensional Array.

Here's my situation :

1. I have several phone prefix from different cities :

> ```
> $CityA = array("021","031","041","051");
>
> $CityB = array("011","012","013","014");
>
> $CityC = array("111","112","113","114");
> ```

1. Also, I have several courier for those cities :

> ```
> $CityA = array("FedEx", "TNT", "DHL");
>
> $CityB = array("YYY Cargo", "USPS");
>
> $CityC = array("UPS", "Regular Mail", "XXX Cargo");
> ```

what I need is :

> INPUT : Phone Prefix, for example 021
>
> OUTPUT : FedEx, TNT or DHL >> Randomly selected

here's another examples :

> 012 >> YYY Cargo (Randomly selected from "YYY Cargo", "USPS")
>
> 112 >> UPS
>
> etc.

It's pretty easy with MySQL, but I want to reduce database connection by using Array. how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use associative arrays for easier access. Since you want to access info by phone prefix, you should use these as keys for the first array. Then, your second array can be indexed by city, as below:

```
$cities = array( 021 => "CityA", 031 => "CityA", 011 => "CityB")
$couriers = array( "CityA" => array("FedEx", "TNT", "DHL"),
                   "CityB" => array("YYY Cargo", "USPS"),
                   "CityC" => array("UPS", "Regular Mail", "XXX Cargo"));
```

So, in your example, for retrieving a courier for prefix 021 you can acces it like this:

```
$city = $cities[$phone_prefix];
$courier_key = array_rand($couriers[$city]);
$courier_name = $couriers[$city][$courier_key];
```

Comment: I tried to use this code : $city = $cities[031]; $courier = array_rand($couriers[$city]); echo $courier; but the result is not Courier name. it's a number between 0 and 2.

Comment: indeed, array_rand returns a random index, not value. I updated the snippet above to also retrieve the name

Answer (score 0):

So you want to specify an area code from "area-code array A", and then generate a random courier from "courier array A"?

Quick and dirty, but you could generate a random number between `0` and `count($couriersA) - 1` (the number of entries in that array) and then select that entry in the array.

If not, you could look at `combinations` - so getting all the possible pairs of area code and courier, then choosing one randomly from that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. You will get random courier for City code ( $value='111'; )

```
$CityA = array("021","031","041","051");
$CityB = array("011","012","013","014");
$CityC = array("111","112","113","114");
$courierA = array("FedEx", "TNT", "DHL");
$courierB = array("YYY Cargo", "USPS");
$courierC = array("UPS", "Regular Mail", "XXX Cargo");

$value = '111';    // Your City Code

if(in_array($value, $CityA)){
    shuffle($courierA);
    echo $courierA[0];
}
else if(in_array($value, $CityB)){
    shuffle($courierB);
    echo $courierB[0];
}
else if(in_array($value, $CityC)){
    shuffle($courierC);
    echo $courierC[0];
}
```

Output: YYY Cargo or USPS